# What is the rule for checking unique data in firebase.

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have multiple users. They can login with their email id using firebase. I am saving their contact information to firebase. Contact Information:(name, phoneNumber), but when I do again login with the same user all data again store to firebase database. I have tried so many rules of firebase database but not getting success.

I have created database in firebase and tried so many rules but some times it is preventing me to write any thing and showing permission denied or some time it is duplicating entry. 
Thanks for help.
[image: Here is my databse]

[image: It is my rule image.]

Answer (score 0):

When you save data at that time dont allocate auto id to User.
Give your user id after login. So this way data duplication will not happen.
Check this db i am saving user detail under userID
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but I am not giving auto id to user. It is the userid  which I receive when I do login. Like in my screen shot HGmSm6fpu4eu20NGAhjvmIo9k3I3 it is the user id. but when I do again login with same user it again save same data in db, I don't want to add duplicate validation via code. 
I want to do this by updating rule tab of firebase.

Comment: I have set this rule 
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}

Comment: I am getting this when I am applying same rule 
<Warning> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] setValue: or removeValue: at ...  failed: permission_denied

Comment: have you test in real device?? And have you configure firebase properly ?

Comment: Yes I have configured firebase properly. but i have checked it in simulator but I think we get same result by running on both.

Comment: I have checked same on device too. Applied ur rule 

{ "rules":
   {
  "messages": { ".read": "auth == null", ".write": "auth == null" } 
 }
}
and getting this error.
 <Warning> [Firebase/Database] setValue: or removeValue: at /messages/kJT9virTHrVztlMaYjc0KVvarsz1/-KlrX6tgmfIHRiJhGwkC failed: permission_denied